# Java Program to display sport played by player on user input and player name on user input sport

Tags: java

```
Player 1 -- chess , hockey , carom 
Player 2 -- cricket , badminton , carom 
Player 3 -- ludo , badminton , pool 
Player 4 -- Table tennis , badminton , snooker
```

Need to display sport played on user input player name 
 
Need to display on user input player name , sport played by him

User can add player name and also can add more sport to individual player

Asked in interview
Got stuck .. Please help with core java 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking for the whole code? or the logic?

Comment: Put some effort...You can write a simple POJO class for this

Comment: Use a `Map<String, Set<String>>` and you're done.

Comment: Logic will help , but very beginner , with little code snippet will help

Comment: Did you even try solving this? If yes, please show your code and explain what the issue is

Comment: please check below code , which i started but could not able to finish

Comment: In the code you posted (which should still be an [edit]) you aren't even trying to display the sport corresponding to a player

Answer (score 0):

here is your solution :

```
package com.sujit;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sport {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter player name : ");
        String playerName = sc.next();
        List<String> list = getSportByPlayerName(playerName);
        for (String string : list) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }

    private static List<String> getSportByPlayerName(String playerName) {
        List<String> listOfSports = new ArrayList<>();  
        if(playerName.equalsIgnoreCase("player1")) {
            listOfSports.add("chess");
            listOfSports.add("hockey");
            listOfSports.add("carrom");
            return listOfSports;
        }
        else if(playerName.equalsIgnoreCase("player2")) {
            listOfSports.add("cricket");
            listOfSports.add("badminton");  
            listOfSports.add("carrom");
            return listOfSports;
                }
        else if(playerName.equalsIgnoreCase("player3")) {
            listOfSports.add("ludo");
            listOfSports.add("badminton");
            listOfSports.add("pool");
            return listOfSports;
        }
        else if(playerName.equalsIgnoreCase("player4")) {
            listOfSports.add("table tennis");
            listOfSports.add("snooker");
            listOfSports.add("badminton");
            return listOfSports;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is pretty bad code and also incorrect - you are comparing with `"player1"` in every single `if`

Comment: @UnholySheep Thanks for sharing valuable feedback. It happen due to copy pasting code here from eclipse